# Force update of Calculator Currency rate

Tags: 12.04, gcalctool

I have gcalctool 6.4.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 
I am using the Currency conversion in Financial mode.

Got to know from [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcalctool/+question/141205) that the tool updates the rates from European Central Bank every 7 days.
I would like to know if i can force update the rates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following before launching the calculator.

`rm .cache/gcalctool/eurofxref-daily.xml`

and then launch the calculator. It will download a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is gnome-calculator in Linux Mint 17.2.
It has its financial rates placed in 
`/home/<user>/.cache/gnome-calculator`
So I used this:

```
rm /home/petr/.cache/gnome-calculator/eurofxref-daily.xml
```

A new xml file with rates appeared, when I started calculator. But anyway, calculator has all rates rounded off curiously. It doesn't give correct values according to these rates.

Comment: Are the rates correct or aren't they?  If they aren't, it doesn't answer the OP's question.